# RelativeLayout with layout_weight doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 4 `LinearLayout` with a `layout_weight` of 0.25 (each one of them uses 25% of the screen height), the first 3 `LinearLayout` contains an `ImageView` and a `RelativeLayout` with a `layout_weight` of 0.5 (they both take 50% of the `LinearLayout` width) and they work fine, the problem occurs on the last `LinearLayout` which contains 2 `RelativeLayout`, this is the structure:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0"
            android:layout_weight=".25">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:background="@color/white">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_news"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/newsTextView"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/newsTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="News"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/mainBlue"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:background="@color/white">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_contacts"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/contactTextView"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/contactTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Contatti"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/mainBlue"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

This LinearLayout doesn't work, it doesn't take the 25% height of the screen and it's just not visible.. Is it a problem with `RelativeLayout` with `layout_weight`? what should I do to fix this?

**EDIT**

This is the whole XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:pew="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0"
            android:layout_weight=".25">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/img"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:background="@color/mainBlue">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Sezione 1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0"
            android:layout_weight=".25">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:background="@color/mainBlue">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Sezione 2"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/img"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0"
            android:layout_weight=".25">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/img"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:background="@color/mainBlue">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Sezione 1"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0"
            android:layout_weight=".25">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:background="@color/white">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_news"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/newsTextView"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/newsTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="News"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/mainBlue"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:background="@color/white">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_contacts"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/contactTextView"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/contactTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Contatti"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/mainBlue"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your whole xml?

Comment: have you tried with  replacing RelativeLayout to LinearLayout? This can tell you what is causing problem? Put your complete XML.

Comment: @vrundpurohit added the whole xml

Comment: @MahendraChhimwal yes I've tried and it didn't work, I've posted the whole xml if you want to check!

Comment: @Signo Share your screen what you want exactly for last two `Linear Layouts`.

Comment: @jaydroider I want the 4 LinearLayout to take 25% height of the screen, the  2 elements inside these LinearLayout has to take 50% of the width, just this

Comment: @Signo Check my answer i have done some modification in your layout try with it.

Comment: @jaydroider I've just tried with your XML but it has the same problem as mine, the last LinearLayout doesn't take 25% of the container's height

Comment: @Signo I didn't get you . Last `Linear Layout` is fit as `0.25 %` taking with my code with both `Relative Layout` in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Add `Linear Layout` as `Root Layout` with `weightSum 1`.

**Refer this.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:pew="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="#FFF">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Sezione 1"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="#FFF">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Sezione 2"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="#FFF">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Sezione 1"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="#FFF">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/newsTextView"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/newsTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="News"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="#FFF">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/contactTextView"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/contactTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Contatti"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I did some edit to the structure but now it's working as intended, thanks! :)

Comment: @Signo Cheers! Up-vote it also brother Thanks :). I was thinking why it is not working to you as expected as it is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to solve this issue:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0"
            android:layout_weight=".25">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
              >
             <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/newsTextView"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/newsTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="News"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
               >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/contactTextView"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/contactTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Contatti"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

hey I tested your code is it seems there is problem in hight you gave to each 4 child layout.

just replace

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >
```

with

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".25"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >
```

and do same for all 4 child views.

**For reference**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:pew="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/cat1" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Sezione 1"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Sezione 2"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/cat2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/cat3" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Sezione 1"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="#fff" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/newsTextView"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/newsTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="News"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="#fff" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/contactTextView"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/contactTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Contatti"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Happy coding.